# viewModel init{} block not called from Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, koin

I have an app which fetches data from an API that should be available globally within the application. This data should be fetched eagerly directly at the app start. I manage dependencies using Koin.
To achieve the desired behaviour, I created a ViewModel class that is tied to the Activity lifecycle using a [`AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) instance:

```
class AppViewModel(
    application: Application,
    private val apiService: ApiService
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    init {
        getData();
        Log.d("INIT", "Hooray, initialization worked!");
    }

    var data: List<DataObject> by mutableStateOf(listOf())

    fun getData() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //... consulting API service
        }
    }

}
```

I initialize this as a Koin module at the App class:

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val appViewModel = module(createdAtStart = true) {
            viewModel { AppViewModel(androidApplication(), get()) }
        }

        startKoin {
            androidContext(this@App)
            modules(/*...., */ appViewModel /*,.... */)
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I start the application, I can see that the data request is not performed, the Log output does not appear, and the data is not present. What do I need to change so that Koin triggers the init block of the ViewModel? If this is not possible, what are alternative ways to achieve this?

Comment: "But whenever I start the application, I can see that the data request is not performed" - the module will be eagerly created but when you add a view model in a koin model it adds it to its own view model provider factory.  This is then called, when required, by a `ViewModelStoreOwner` at injection point - `private val appViewModel by viewModel()` - until injection it will not be created as koin relies on the `ViewModelStoreOwner` to decide whether it needs to generate the view model.  Sounds like you just need to create a single Repository that can be accessed by multple sources.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Regarding a repository, I already have a repository class with getter methods. So do you recommend to move the data variable and the getData() function there, inject the repository into the Applicaiton class, and call the getData method there? And then, all other Activites injecting the repository will get exactly this repository instance, right?

Comment: I recommend you move the `getData` to the shared/single repository instance init block.  Include its definition  (`single { myRepository(get(), get() ...)}` )in a module with `createdAtStart = true` (included after you set the androidContext) - that should be enough for it to create the Repository instance (called defintion by Koin) an initialise its constructor- basically its eagerly created rather than lazily.

Comment: Thanks, this worked surprisingly well. If you want to articulate a formal answer, I will accept it.